# xml parsing and unicode (again)

Tags: python, xml, unicode, elementtree

xml header:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><points>
```

xml data snippet:

```
<point>
<id>1781</id><lon>43.245766666667</lon><lat>56.636883333333</lat>
<type>vert</type><last_update>2016-11-18 22:55:11</last_update>
<active>1</active><verified>1</verified><international>0</international><name>Vеrshilovo</name><name_ru>Вершилово</name_ru><city/><belongs>АОН</belongs><inde
```

code:

```
tree = ET.parse(XMLFIL)
root = tree.getroot()
allpoints=root.findall('point')
for point in allpoints:
 id=point.find('id').text
 name=point.find('name').text.encode('utf8')
 print name
```

This will reward me with "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encode' " If I leave out the 'encode' I get the infamous ''ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u0435' in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)'

NB the error is with the 'e' of 'Vershilovo' : it looks ok like that but a hexdump of the xml data gives

```
00000000  56 e5 72 73 68 69 6c 6f  76 6f 0a                 |V.rshilovo.|
```

I found several related questions but none brought me a solution. The root cause may well be incorrect encoding of my xml data but I have no control over it. I can quite live with having to reset illegal values to some default like "???" or such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like some of the items don't have a `text` attribute.  You could use a try-except block or use a default value if `text` is `None`, eg:

```
name = (point.find('name').text or '').encode('utf8')
```

Another example, using an if statement:

```
name = point.find('name').text
if name: 
    name = name.encode('utf8')
```

Comment: I can't really understand how it works - but it does! The output now includes the 'irregular' charter, neatly converted:     00000000  31 37 38 31 20 56 d0 b5  72 73 68 69 6c 6f 76 6f  |1781 V..rshilovo|

Comment: I just use an empty string in case `text` is `None` so python won't throw an exception. You can also use try-except or if-else, but i like 1-liners;)